# Probability of one pair in poker dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was working through a textbook on probability for self-study/review. One question asks you to show that the probability of getting one pair when rolling five dice is 0.4630. One pair means two dice are of the same number and the rest are all different numbers.

I misread the question, so my logic was wrong but I got the answer right. What did I end up counting? Why does my formula work?

My answer was:$\frac{ {6 \choose 1}{5 \choose 4}5!}{6^5}$

Comment: this is not clear.  What constitutes "one pair"?  In poker, generally, saying a hand is of type $X$ precludes all better hands.  Thus $66666$ would not be "one pair".  Neither would $66555$ and so on.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. One pair means two dice are of the same number and the rest are all different numbers.

Comment: In any event:  $6$ choices for the pair, then $\binom 52$ places to put the pair.  Then $5$ ways to populate the first singleton, $4$ for the second, and $3$ for the third.  That's the numerator.  Denominator is $6^5$ as you say.  That gives $0.462962963$, matching the official answer.

Comment: But I used $ {5 \choose 4}?$

Comment: Should say:  I don't see why your formula works (though it is easy to check that it does).  I mean, I don't see a nice combinatorial line of thought that gets me to that formula.  Of course there are a lot of coincidences that happen with small numbers.  Maybe that's what we have here.  Or, of course,  I might be missing something.

Comment: I guess it is just coincidence that my formula works.

Comment: Is this line of reasoning wrong? $ {6 \choose 1}$ ways of selecting the pair. ${5 \choose 4}$ ways of selecting the remaining numbers. 5! ways of ordering the selected numbers. All of this divided by the sample space of $6^5$.

Comment: There are only $3$ remaining numbers.  You've burned two choices with your pair, and you now need to choose $3$ values for the singletons.